# Как правильно передать значение в QTimer::singleShot с формы ui

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Имею такой код в методе

```
QTimer::singleShot(ui->spinBox->value(), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```

Программа успешно запускается, работает. Но когда вызываю метод с этой строкой - получаю исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос. Как передавать значение со спинбокса в качестве параметра для метода?

Comment: Проблема не в этой, либо не только в этой строке, т.к. синтаксически вызов написан корректно. Проверьте с помощью отладчика наличие объектов ui->spinBox и loop на момент вызова строки.

Comment: @alexis031182, http://i.imgur.com/Uq2HQRN.png главная форма запускается и значения spinbox изменяются.

Comment: Вам необходимо привести минимальный компилируемый пример, воспроизводящий ошибку, в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение сам нашел. Изменил просто модификатор доступа к ui с private на public.